# jars no longer seem to be signed. JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry

Tags: java, security, netbeans-7, java-web-start

NB 7.4RC2, Win 7

In Java Control Panel, the "Keep Temporary Internet Files" checkbox is checked.

I am signing my Web Start application with trusted certificates.
However, the 3rd party jars in dist/lib seem to be unsigned.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\jarsigner" -verify
>   javafx-dialogs-0.0.3.jar
>
> jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)

So when I run my application in the debugger, it refuses to start complaining of unsigned jars

```
ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar
```

I get the same error when I run with self signed jars, “Found unsigned entry in resource”. It is as if NetBeans stopped signing the jars.

I deleted all temporary files in the Java cache from Java Control Panel. Now it fails to run clicking both Run and Debug in the IDE, and also copying the dist folder to the desktop and clicking the jnlp file.

```
ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: file:/C:/Users/me/Desktop/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar
```

while building:

> Warning:  The signer certificate will expire within six months.
>   Signing JAR:
>   C:\Users\me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp\dist\lib\RXTXcomm.jar to
>   C:\Users\me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp\dist\lib\RXTXcomm.jar as
>   my_key54321

while running:

```
network: Cache entry found [url: file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar
cache: Resource file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar has expired.
network: ResponseCode for file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar : 200
network: Encoding for file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar : null
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Wed Feb 04 19:07:10 CST 2009,length=60866
```

........

> security: Trust for:
>   file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyApp/dist/lib/RXTXcomm.jar
>   has ended: Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 CST 1969

Does anyone know what is causing this?

**Update:** In NetBeans, I selected Project Properties and under Run, selected Run As “default configuration”. Earlier, Run As “WebStart” was selected. Now it starts normally. Was it a NetBeans bug or a feature?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I created a JavaFX project, added some deployment configuration (sign enabled, signing certificate), and running as Standalone works fine, but running as WebStart, or simply opening the generated html (with it's applet) or double-clicking the JNLP file, displays the same exception.

I realized that toggling "Enable BLOB Signing", generates different content inside the built Jar's META-INF folder.

Answer (score 2):

WebVPN Java Plugins fail to load after upgrade to Java 7 Update 45 with the following General Exception error - 'com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource:

Conditions: Windows or Mac OSX machines using Java 7 Update 45.

Workaround: 1) Disable the option 'Keep temporary files on my computer' on the Java Control Panel -> General -> Settings. This works for both Mac OSX and Windows.

or

2) Downgrade Java to version 7 Update 40 or below