# Unsigned entry - JWS

Tags: java, web-applications, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I am trying to learn how JWS works and got stuck with the below error

> com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in
>   resource: http://localhost:9292/TestJnlp.jar  at
>   com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown
>   Source)

went thru a lot of related post below could got the answers i am looking for.

> [Found unsigned entry in resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923635/found-unsigned-entry-in-resource)
>
> [jars no longer seem to be signed. JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333674/jars-no-longer-seem-to-be-signed-jarsigningexception-found-unsigned-entry)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309730/javaws-keep-temporary-files-unchecked-%E2%87%92-found-unsigned-entry-in-resource

Question 1 : why the JWS application is checking for the signing by default and what are the two components which are checked/verified by this signature ?

In general when we sign a file (by sender), its signature is verified by the receiver or vice versa similarly what are the components here for this error ?

Question 2: how it(jar) can be signed so that this error can be fixed ?

Question 3: any setting to disable it ?

Comment: Its weird but updating java to 8 from 7 is not showing the problem, but new error is cropping " class not found!" will post a new question with details.

Comment: new query link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260333/jws-class-not-found-error