# JWS Class not found error

Tags: java, web-applications, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I was trying to explore how the JWS works end to end, was following this blog.
[JWS tutorial link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/web-start/java-web-start-getting-started/)

initially got "unsigned jar error" [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233532/unsigned-entry-jws)- may be fixed now,
but now its throwing class not found, tried multiple things like creating a class without package etc etc, but still its not working. A new class with the steps etc.

I am not sure if its some version compatibility issue or not.

**Apache tomcat - 8.0.23**
**Java -1.8.0_40-b26**

---

JNLP file details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="JNLPExample.jnlp">

     <information>
          <title>JNLP Example</title>
          <vendor>Java Code Geeks</vendor>
          <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
          <description>JNLP Testing</description>
     </information>

     <security>
          <all-permissions/>
     </security>

     <resources>
          <j2se version="1.6+" />
          <jar href="JNLPExample.jar" />
     </resources>

     <application-desc main-class="main.javacodegeeks.JNLPExample" />
</jnlp>
```

Class details

```
package main.javacodegeeks;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class JNLPExample extends JFrame {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 4968624166243565348L;

     private JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello from Java Code Geeks!");

     public JNLPExample() {
          super("Jave Web Start Example");
          this.setSize(350, 200);
          this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          this.setLayout(null);
     }

     public void addButtons() {
          label.setSize(200, 30);
          label.setLocation(80, 50);
          this.getContentPane().add(label);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          JNLPExample exp = new JNLPExample();
          exp.addButtons();
          exp.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

[image: JaNeLA- Output]

[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]
[image: Error 3]

Comment: What is your question, exactly?  And how do you expect anyone to debug a CNFE when you provide no detail on the package structure and class name, nor the content of the JNLP?  Sometimes I think people asking questions believe that the people who provide answers do so by magic. Another tip:   Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: sorry for not being clear, added the jnlp file and class details

Comment: added the output snap from JaNeLA as well

Comment: *"added the output snap from JaNeLA as well"* `</head-desk>` Don't post images of textual information!  JaNeLA can produce a text report.

Comment: BTW - when the server is running and you click [this link to the Jar](http://localhost:8080/JNLPExample.jar), what is the result?  Does the browser offer the Jar for download?

Comment: Yes, it gets downloaded, added the error snaps in my original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82579/discussion-between-pallab-and-andrew-thompson).

Comment: When i added a manifest file while creating the jar its working. Is it mandatory to create the manifest file ? can't it be pulled from the jnlp description  <application-desc main-class=>?

Comment: *"can't it be pulled from the jnlp description"*  As long as the JNLP specifies a main class it can be left out of the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

JWS needs the external jars to b in the \lib\ext directory.